# Handle with very short and very long sequences with Neural Network

Tags: nlp, lstm, multiclass-classification, embeddings, sequence

I am working on multi-class problem with sequences. My dataset is composed of sequences of data with different length.

E.g. 1500 labeled samples: 500 datapoint belongs to class A, 500 class B and 500 class C.
For A and B the sequence length is 400 and 1000 respectively, and for class C the sequence length is 100.

In order to train the model I have applied post-padding on the sequences so that all the sequences have the same length. The resulting dataset has this shape (1500,1000).

I have tried first EMBEDDING+LSTM (mask_zero=True) to map and classify the sequences but even if the model achieve very high accuracy, evaluate the model with random/fake data it will classify based on the sequences' length: suggesting that the model is learning on the lengths instead of values.

The main problem is that the model is much more learning on 0s even if we use "mask_zero" into the embedding layer. My question is:

Does someone can suggest an approach to **deal with very long sequences**? Considering that we have very short and very long sequences to predict?

I am exploring another different approach:

1. Train an Autoencoder (ANN or 1DCNN) to reduce the sequence length. Use the encoder and train again the Embedding layer + LSTM layer.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of data is it? Text or numbers? Are the data points related to each other to try a compression method?

Comment: Sequences are numbers. Each elements in a single sequence are related . what's the compression you suggests?

Comment: If you use a logarithm, you can compress float data efficiently, but you might loss some information. For instance: log(20 000 000) = 7.03 and log(2 000) = 3.30. I used to apply this solution in similar cases than you have, and the results were good.

Comment: how exactly should I apply this methodology? my dataset consists in a sequences of fixed length. if I understood I should apply the log to the length?

Comment: Can you give an example of the values of a sequence please?

Comment: yes of course sequences are something like:


Out[6]:


shape (2649, 1019)

array([[21.5, 26.8, 27.9, ...,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [13.4, 11.8, 10.8, ...,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [13.3, 11.6, 13.1, ...,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       ...,
       [ 1.7,  7.3, 11.4, ...,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [26.8, 25.6, 30.9, ...,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 7.6,  8.4,  9.7, ...,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])

Comment: Thanks, I see much better. In fact you are limited by LSTM memory : Large LSTM models don't go beyond 500 time steps. Using an autoencoder is a very good solution indeed but you can also use other types of neural networks like ResNet or CNN. For example: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-convolutional-neural-network-models-for-time-series-forecasting/

Comment: Attention mechanisms could be interesting, as they are able to deal with very long times series, but it would probably require more investigation. For example: https://lucenaresearch.com/2019/11/18/how-transformers-with-attention-networks-boost-time-series-forecasting/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Check if text preprocessing is done correctly.
2. With different sequence lengths (Ex: 1000, 750, 500 etc.)
3. After the LSTM layer, try adding the ANN layers and check the results.
4. Check the Transformers architecture for text classification.
   Reference: https://ai-brewery.medium.com/simple-chatbot-using-bert-and-pytorch-part-1-2735643e0baa

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. I don't need text processing since the sequences are already floating points values. And yes I have tried an architecture with embedding layer +lstm +ANN but it doesn't work: with random data the model predicts the classes based on sequence's length.